# a better way to create an email template with bash

Tags: linux, bash

Using bash to create an email template:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="today is "
VAR2="a good day"

echo "Good Morning" >> /tmp/email_template
echo $VAR1$VAR2 >> /tmp/email_template
echo "Best regards" >> /tmp/email_template
cat /tmp/email_template|mutt -s "Hello!" destination@gmail.com
```

is there something more clean to create an email template?

Comment: `mutt -s "Hello!" destination@gmail.com <<EOF literal_new_line_content_here EOF` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HERE doc as mentioned by a comment above or you can use a block like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="today is "
VAR2="a good day"

{
echo "Good Morning"
echo "$VAR1$VAR2"
echo "Best regards"
} | mutt -s "Hello!" 'destination@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it using the HERE doc approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="today is "
VAR2="a good day"

mutt -s "Hello!" destination@gmail.com <<EOF
Good Morning
$VAR1$VAR2
Best regards
EOF
```